# How to reduce rows lookup when using LIMIT MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have the following table with Index on `id` and Foreign Key on `activityID`:

`comment (id, activityID, text)`

and the following query:

```sql
SELECT <cols> FROM `comment` WHERE `comment`.`activityID` = 1257 ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 20;
```

I basically want to get only the first 20 comments for this activity that has 1165, however, this is the result of a describe:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key         key_len ref     rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE      comment ref     activityID      activityID  4       const   1165    NULL
```

Essentially, it is looking through all comments for this activity before deciding to limit it.

We tested this query under high load when an activity has 200,000 comments and the query takes 5+ seconds, whereas on the same load, an activity with 30 comments takes a couple of ms.

PS: If I remove the `WHERE` clause, an EXPLAIN says it will only lookup a single row (don't know if that's the case really):

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key         key_len ref     rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE      comment index   NULL            PRIMARY     4       NULL    1       NULL
```

Is it possible to optimize this kind of query in any way?

Thank you.

Comment: What happens if you add an `ORDER BY` clause? LIMIT without ORDER BY is usually a code smell, since you don't know which 20 you'll get.

Comment: Actually the query we are using has a `ORDER BY id DESC` clause. I will update.

Comment: Probably not a big deal,  would actually being specific with the selection help; `SELECT \`text\` FROM` rather than `*`?

Comment: The actual code selects specific columns, I just stripped that to make it easier to read, and it wouldn't make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

The ordering is causing the slowness.

The query uses the `activityID` index to find all the rows with that ID. Then it has to read all 200,000 comments and sort them by `id` to find the last 20.

Add a composite index so it can use an index for the ordering:

```
ALTER TABLE comment ADD INDEX (activityID, id);
```

Note that you will no longer need the index on `activityID` by itself, since it's a prefix of this new index.

Comment: It didn't make any difference. Tried without any ordering, tried ordering by id with that index you suggested and the `EXPLAIN` returns exactly the same thing.

Comment: Even after you removed the old index?

Comment: It is a Foreign Key

Comment: That's OK. Since it's the prefix of this new key, it will still be usable as the foreign key.

Comment: My point is that `ORDER BY` doesn't make any difference, I even tried using `FORCE INDEX (`activityID_id`)`and it is the same.

Comment: I'm not sure why. This should be exactly the index it needs to optimize this ordering. If it doesn't fix it, then MySQL is just not able to optimize this query.

Comment: @MaurícioGiordano if cardinality number is a bug simply remove your comments. If something else is a bug please clarify

Answer (score -1):

Use offset

```
SELECT <cols> FROM `comment` WHERE `comment`.`activityID` = 1257 ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 0,20;
```

In limit clause add `0` as an offset to get only the first 20 comments

Comment: But the default value to the offset is zero if no offset is supplied, so this doesn't seem to actually change anything?

Comment: Oh sorry my mistake

Answer (score -1):

Just add two separate indexes on `activityID` and `id`. That should help you in `ORDER BY` too. There is no hard and fast rules in optimizations, but you need to try various methods.

Do it this way:

```
ALTER TABLE comment ADD INDEX (id);
ALTER TABLE comment ADD INDEX (activityID);
```

I think this will help.

Comment: `id` always have an index by default. `activityID` is a foreign key.

Comment: I don't know why you down voted my answer, you didn't write anywhere that your `id` is primary key in the question. That's why I wrote to make it sure. Anyways if `id` is primary key you still need to create index on `activityID`. Because foreign keys are not automatically indexed in MyIsam engine but only in InnoDB.

Plus this is general rule of thumb that SQL query will traverse through all records, which are part of fulfilled index condition. In case you want to further reduce your results, you defiantly need to some composite key combinations to achieve lesser number of rows.